# JavaScript can't get value off function's array parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

i am trying to order some images in columns based on their height and i have the following code.
the problem is that even though imgHeights.length works fine, imgHeights[i] (in the redrawThumbs function) doesn't return a value.
what am i doing wrong? thanks =)

```
function redrawThumbs(imgHeights){
  // some irrelevant code here

  // initialise an array that will hold all the column's heights
  var colHeights = new Array(cols);
  for(a=0; a <= colHeights.length - 1; ++a){
    colHeights[a] = 0;
  }

  // take each image's height and add it to the shortest column
  for(i=0; i <= imgHeights.length - 1; ++i){
    var shortestCol = 0;

    for(c=0; c <= colHeights.length - 2; ++c){
      if(colHeights[c+1] < colHeights[c]){
        shortestCol = colHeights[c+1];
      }
    }

    alert("imgHeights[" + i + "] " + imgHeights[i]);

    colHeights[shortestCol] += imgHeights[i];
  }
}

// make an array of image heights
var imgHeights = new Array(totalThumbs);    
for(i=1; i <= totalThumbs; ++i){
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
  imgHeights[i-1] = this.height;
}
img.src = i + ".jpg";

// call function that orders the images
redrawThumbs(imgHeights);
```

Comment: You may want to add some indentation to your code as well as add in the missing `}`. It's hard to tell where your `redrawThumbs()` method ends.

Comment: i added the missing }. indentation... 2 spaces isnt that bad for small code like this :D

the weirdest thing i just noticed while debugging is that the bottom for where i create the imgHeights array, well i put an alert in there printing the i variable and it always shows the last number of the loop. i have no idea why this happens, cause it is working fine when i create elements with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issues is that the `i` variable is captured by reference, not by value so, for all the callback of `img.onload` is getting the same value of `i`. Consider changing the `onload` assignment to,

```
var loadedCount = 0;
img.onload = (function (i) { 
    return function () { 
        imgHeights[i - 1] = this.height;
        if (++loadedCount == totalThumbs) allLoaded();
    };
})(i);

function allLoaded() {
    // called after all the images have been loaded.
}
```

this captures a copy of the value of `i` at the point of auto-execute function execution and calls `allLoaded()` after all the images have been loaded.

Comment: i tried this and added an alert like alert(imgHeight[i - 1]); below the code but it doesn't even appear. am i doing it wrong? how can i verify the values

maybe i being already a variable is messing with it being a function name?

Comment: If I take your code literally you need to add a `src` property to the image. Also, the callbacks will occur after your call to `redrawThumbs()` is called.

Comment: ah there was an "s" missing in imgHeights. now the alert appears but i still get undefined when i try to print the contents of imgHeights (i made a new loop outside and after this loop)

Comment: i have added a src below what you gave me. still undefined :(

Comment: im sorry i didnt get the part where you said the callbacks will occur after my call to redrawThumbs(). does this mean i should add the src after redrawThumbs?

sorry for being so noob :)

Comment: When are you checking? The `onload` fires asynchronously. You cannot check immediately, you need to wait until the `onload` event fires.

Comment: im not sure when i should check. this code is just meant to fill this array with image heights and nothing else

Comment: You are checking before the `onload` events have fired. Try counting the number of thumbs loading in the `onload` callback and then checking after `totalThumbs` images have loaded.

Comment: i still cant make it to work. this is what i have now

http://jsfiddle.net/BdQQ3/1/

Comment: can you write it again i was updating to show you and i think i overwrote yours. im sorry

Comment: ok i think i finally made it: http://jsfiddle.net/BdQQ3/2/

thank you so much for your help! i would have never made it without you